# Realistic tree falling animation

Tags: animation

I have a simple tree in my scene. I'm going to have it fall over and when I do, I (of course) want the branches to shake around in a realistic way, and impact on the ground. is there a way to simulate this?

Comment: Can you add an image of your tree topology? ... To let us see a structure ...

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can cheat physics by

- creating a dummy of tree simplified into some lowlopy version
  (like here by *Convex Hull* operator)

[image]

- run **Cloth** sim on this dummy
- and for highres Tree use **Mesh Deform** modifier to transfer simulation

Result in here looks pour, but if you will care more about topology result could be better.

[image]

... or probably better create a low-poly tree as extruded faces (roughly in direction of main branches), use a Cloth and for high-poly tree use *Surface Deform* modifier.