The chain is breaking apart
I've designed a chain using Rhino 3D and would like to attach it to a mannequin. I've imported the mannequin and chain into Blender. I would like to activate gravity and have the necklace lay on the mannequin by the effect of gravity. I've used rigid body for the chain and set the shape to mesh. The chain breaks apart and the scene is very laggy. My goal is only to attach the chain to the mannequin. I won't make any animations. Is there a simple way to do that? I am completely Blender beginner. Here is a link to the file . Thank you in advance.


Update1: 


In this case IT IS probably better to use a mesh line with a cloth modifier and use it as dummy for Your neckles with Mesh Deform modifier - target to mesh line. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/239405/2214 oř here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229467/2214

Oř here just without Bones https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228398/2214

So much to learn! I will do my best and get back.

I am not sure what I did wrong. Here is what I did. I've joint all chain links and pendants into one object called necklace. I've drawn a bezier line along the chain and converted it to a pipe shape using Bevel round and then converted the pipe to a mesh. Then I applied Mesh Deform modifier to necklace mesh and chose the pipe mesh as the midifier. Please have a look at the result above.

Using physics (for such kind of model) will be too heavy to calculate (each segment of your chain with each others on line) and full of errors (penetration, interruptions, etc.) I don't think there is an easy way in blender just use your model directly in blender an succeed with Rigid Body sim.
... for that I'm suggesting you to

model a "dummy" of your necklace
add Cloth Sim modifier to it (to minimise mentioned issues)
and use it as Target for Surface Deform modifier added to your hires model.

Here I created a dummy object ... place a face under the name and with edge selected, hold Ctrl and click in chain direction to generate a square face. Continue to follow chain shape around to cover whole hires model.

Assign Cloth modifier (default setup seems to be fine)
Than select your necklace and add Surface Deform modifier with Target to dummy ...

Because rings holding names were squeezed so I separated names as solo objects and used Parent to Vertex feature to stick to dummy. just select name object than dummy switch to edit mode select three vertices in triangles position (one that is in ring location) and Ctrl+P.
Result

Your file is big I tried it to simplified, but still big so take it from here (no need to login, there is a direct link to download at the bottom of popup window - black text).

Thank you for your effort. I am still struggling to make this work. Would you please recommend a course I can take to help me with this? Maybe on Udemy or another platform.

I dont know what is your specific issue you are dealing with, so it is hard to recomemnd any tutorial. You can edit your Q by adding more details about current issue or ask completely a new Q ... if you have an issue to use modifier search for some tuts.

What I need to learn is putting any type of necklace (imported from Rhino) on a mannequin under the effect of gravity. The necklace could have a name plate, a charm or multiple charms...etc. So, it is something related to physics and animation more than 3d modeling.

Thank you! The result is much better, but why the chain is not touching the mannequin? It is floating. Can it be solved by decreasing the size of the dummy surface?

I'm on tablet now ... So just guessing ... In Collision properties Distance or Margin should be set lower ... Or so, I will check that tomorrow if you don't succeed.
